# Shortcut to get back to previous folder in PCManFM

Tags: shortcut-keys, pcmanfm

Is there a keyboard shortcut for getting back to previous folder in [PCManFM](https://wiki.lxde.org/en/PCManFM)?

I couldn't find it in the `Help` > `Keyboard Navigation` page, nor in the `Preferences`.

PS. Using PCManFM 1.2.5 on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Alt+back arrow works for me (pcmanfm 1.2.5).

Comment: You haven't said what OS/release you are talking about, but I tested a standard install of Lubuntu 18.04 LTS and the key listed in the `pcmanfm` menu works correctly for me.

Comment: @DKBose Thanks! Do you wish to submit it as an answer?

Comment: Backspace works for pcmanfm-qt 0.14.1

Comment: @guiverc I edited my question to embed OS and PCManFM version info, thank you! Which keys are you talking about exactly? I read again those listed in v.1.2.5 and there's none about getting back to previous folder.

Comment: @Gryu ah great... that works too.

Comment: @Campa feel free to post your own answer and ping me if you do.

Comment: Click "Go" on the menu and you can see both your options, and keystrokes required to jump there directly without use of menu.

Answer (score 3):

I found the follwing shortcuts:

1. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> / <kbd>Right</kbd> for navigating the folders history back and forth
2. <kbd>Backspace</kbd> for going to parent folder

---

<sub>Thanks to @DKBose and @Gyru for the useful comments.</sub>

<sub>NOTE: this is actually readily visible under the `Go` menu. Thanks @guiverc</sub>